# How can I always display the remaining battery time on the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, battery, time

I want to have the remaining time always visible, and not to have to click/hover to see it.

Is it possible only with some gadget? If so, which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice freeware for you!

http://osirisdevelopment.com/BatteryBar/